# Make target with two words

Tags: make, gnu-make

I'm using a Makefile to compile my [Clean](http://clean.cs.ru.nl) code. My Clean files have file names of the format `*.icl` and are compiled to binaries with the same name but without `.icl`. This is done with the rule:

```
$(EXE): % : %.icl | copy
    $(CLM) $(CLM_LIBS) $(CLM_INC) $(CLM_OPTS) $@ -o $@
```

I would now like to add a rule which allows me to run a binary. Currently, I'm often doing

```
make some_module && ./some_module
```

I would like to have a make target which depends on the rule above and runs the module. However, the name of the module is already a target itself for compilation alone and I'd like to keep it that way. What I would like is a target with two words that I can call with `make run some_module` which then depends on the rule above and runs `./some_module` afterwards.

Is it possible to create targets with multiple words?

I tried to make a rule (now still without dependency) with the following:

```
run $(EXE):
    ./$@
```

Running `make run some_module` results in many recipes being 'overridden' and 'ignored' and finally `./run` not existing.

```
Makefile:24: warning: overriding recipe for target 'tut7_2_2'
Makefile:21: warning: ignoring old recipe for target 'tut7_2_2'
Makefile:24: warning: overriding recipe for target 'support_check'
Makefile:21: warning: ignoring old recipe for target 'support_check'
[...]
Makefile:24: warning: overriding recipe for target 'drawingframe'
Makefile:21: warning: ignoring old recipe for target 'drawingframe'
./run
/bin/bash: ./run: No such file or directory
Makefile:24: recipe for target 'run' failed
make: *** [run] Error 127
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [inspect `MAKECMDGOALS`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/222271) to detect the presence of one goal while building another goal. Either make the `%: %.icl` run detect the presence of the `run` goal, or make the `run` goal inspect what executables are mentioned as targets. If you pass more than one executable as a target, the first method causes each to be run right after it's built, while the second causes all the runs to happen at the end.

The downside of this approach is that it doesn't scale well with other features. For example, if you define a target with multiple executables as dependencies, the method with a `run` target won't work.

```
EXE = foo bar experimental
released: foo bar
run: $(filter $(EXE), $(MAKECMDGOALS))
        set -e; for x in $^; do ./$x; done
```

Here `make released run` won't run anything.

What I normally do for this case is to define a “run” target for each executable. This keeps each target expressed as a single word, which is a major advantage. It's simple and doesn't break other features.

```
$(EXE): %.run: %
        ./$(@:.run=)
all.run: $(EXE:=.run)
```

Then I run `make {foo,bar}.run` if I want to built and test `foo` and `bar`, or `make all.run` to build and run them all.

Answer (score 3):

You might be able to use [$(MAKECMDGOALS)](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Goals.html) to force `run` to be executed last among other targets specified in the command line.  The following example uses C because I don't know Clean.

```
EXE = a b c

%: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $< $(LDFLAGS)

all: $(EXE)

clean:
    rm -f $(EXE)

run: $(filter-out run, $(MAKECMDGOALS))
    @for i in $^; do ./$$i; done

.PHONY: all clean run
```

`make run program` might seem a little clumsy because it always puts unnecessary output `program is up to date`.

```
$ cat a.c
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv) { printf("This is %s\n", argv[0]); return 0; }
$ cp a.c b.c
$ cp a.c c.c

$ make run a b
cc  -o a a.c
cc  -o b b.c
This is ./a
This is ./b
make: 'a' is up to date.
make: 'b' is up to date.
```

`make program run` makes no such output and it might be more natural as English.

```
$ make c run
cc  -o c c.c
This is ./c
```

Comment: Very nice, I wasn't aware of `MAKECMDGOALS`. Thanks a lot.